# Plone 3.2.1 on Fedora 10 with Active Directory Authentication

Tags: ldap, plone, plone-3.x

I have gone through tons of documents over the internet in enabling Active Directory Authentication for Plone 3 using LDAPMultiplugins, PlonePAS etc., but none of them are working for me.

Is there any one who has successfully done this? Even if this has accomplished on Windows, it is ok!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current best-practice is plone.app.ldap:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.app.ldap

Answer (score 0):

I've had a few experiences with Plone 3 + LDAP + Active Directory in Windows.

The worst problems I've had were related to installing the Python LDAP libraries, and configuring them (specially configuring the library to recognize the CA certificate for the SSL server certificate in a LDAP over SSL connection).

What exactly is the problem you are facing?